# MongoEngine specify read preference on query

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, mongoengine, replicaset

I am using Mongo 2.6, Pymongo 2.7.2 and Mongoengine 0.8.7. For a particular read query, I want to use the secondary of my replica set. Hence, as specified in the mongoengine documentation [here](https://mongoengine.readthedocs.io/en/v0.8.7/apireference.html#mongoengine.queryset.QuerySet.read_preference) I wrote my query as follows :

```
from pymongo.read_preferences import ReadPreference    
<collection_name>.objects().read_preference(ReadPreference.SECONDARY_PREFERRED)
```

However, the query is always going to the primary it seems ( The logs for this query are always seen only in the primary ). Is the syntax correct? If yes, how do I verify if the secondary is being queried?

Comment: Could be due to [this bug](https://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine/pull/1042) if you're chaining another method such as skip, limit, etc.

Comment: I am chaining it with the order_by method but my Pymongo version is 2.7.2 and the bug is in any version >= 3.0. I guess it is broken in 2.7.2 as well.

Comment: The message reads "As of now, the fix only works for pymongo ver < 3.0.", so I thought both 2.7 and 3+ where affected (although differently). You may want to try without order_by, to double-check.

Answer (score 1):

Figured out what the issue was. In the MongoEngine **"connect"** method, the **replicaSet** parameter needed to be specified as follows:

`connect(db = "my_db", replicaSet = "my_replica_set_name", host = "hostname", port = "port_number")`

The syntax of the read preference is correct as specified above. Passing in the **replicaSet** parameter made it work.